# UIWebView can't display PHP files

Tags: php, iphone, uiwebview

I am using a `UIWebView` to display local `php` file, but id shows only `"undefined"` why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how do you plan to serve the php file in iphone? Unless there is an internal web server, you cannot view a php file from a web view.

Comment: what about this tutorial ?http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-build-an-rss-reader-with-jquery-mobile-2/ ??

Comment: if you closely look at the tutorial you will see that the web app works in safari browser of MAC, which means there is an OS with Apache and PHP built in. So another close look at then end when the web app has a shortcut on IOS, you will see a URL in the IOS safari, which is not localhost or something internal.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP file being a local file to the iPhone has no way of being executed for there is no web server set up.