# Display a local web page in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am trying to display a local web page in a `UIWebView`. The local web page is a `PHP` file and stored in the Supporting Files folder then a folder I created called webpages. I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
@synthesize web;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"php" inDirectory:@"web"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [web loadRequest:request];
    [web setDelegate:self];
    [web loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: You're trying to run a PHP script which renders the webpage? Because you can't serve PHP unless you also run a webserver which executes the code. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326210/uiwebview-cant-display-php-files which deals with the same topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can not load `PHP` file in `UIWebView`, Because `PHP` needs server to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a local php file through UIWebView. PHP is a server side scripting language. OS X (and Windows) don't know how to interpret php code.

It seems to be an iPhone app your making, and running local php in your iPhone app is a no-go, and will continue to be for the foreseeable future.